# Importing HDF files into ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mosaic, hdf

I have hdf files of monthly ocean productivity, but the data is not displaying on my map. I tried to unzip the file twice, define the projection, extract the subdataset, create a mosaic dataset, and add rasters to the mosaic dataset. Below are the website of the data and my results from ArcGIS Desktop.

http://orca.science.oregonstate.edu/1080.by.2160.monthly.hdf.vgpm.m.chl.m.sst.php

[image: ArcGIS Results]

[image: ArcGIS Results Continued]

Comment: I have the same problem with ArcPro from this datasource, but also tried other sources and file formats such as HDF5. HDF5 loads in Pro, but doesn't display properly.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.